# SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toBlob' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, cors

I am extracting an image from video using the following code, but got some error:

SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toBlob' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

After some SO research, it appears to be a security issue with image CORS and some solution suggested to set image.crossOrigin to 'Anonymous'. But none of them seemed to be applied to my code below.

How/where should I make the changes to fix this error? Thanks.

```
 video.onseeked = () => {
            const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
            canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            canvas.toBlob(resolve, "image/jpeg", 1.0); // Where the error happens
        };
```

Comment: You add the same `crossOrigin` attribute to the `<video>` (after you set up the server where the video is hosted to correctly send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin allowing your domain).